# Error 1064 in SQL script while exporting from MySql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting an error in the SQL script while exporting a model from MySQL workbench. Been looking around for a bit but can't find any answers that could help in this specific case.

Trying to export a script created in MySQL workbench to phpMyAdmin. Can anyone see what is wrong with this part of the script?

> Executing SQL script in server
>   ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
>           REFERENCES `mydb`.`Staff` ()
>           ON DELETE NO ACTION
>           ON UPDATE NO ACTI' at line 15

**SQL Code**

```
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`course`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`course` (
          `idcourse` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `describtion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `week start` DATE NOT NULL,
          `week end` DATE NOT NULL,
          `ECTS` INT NOT NULL,
          `course responsible` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `level` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idcourse`),
          CONSTRAINT `course responsible`
            FOREIGN KEY ()
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Staff` ()
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `level`
            FOREIGN KEY ()
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Level` ()
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: The foreign key defintions are empty - no referencing or referenced fields are provided.

Comment: No referencing?

Comment: The empty brackets must contain field names. Pls read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Check the foreign key syntax

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name>( 
column1    data_type[(size)] ,  
column2    data_type[(size)] ,  
constraint(constraint_name) 
FOREIGN KEY  [column1,column2...] 
REFERENCES [primary_key_table] (column_list_of_primary_key_table) ...);
```